# is there a frame size limitation in opencv VideoWriter?

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

When using opencv to save a bunch of pictures to a video file the file won't open unless I resize the image:
`(Windows error - "This item is in a format we don't support. 0xc00d36b4")`

My code looks like this:

```
import cv2
import os

input_path = "input_images_folder_path"
imgs_lst = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\...\input_path")
outvid_path = r"C:\Users\...\output.avi"

image0 = input_path +"\\"+ imgs_lst[0]
img0 = cv2.imread(image)    
size = (int(img0.shape[1]), int(img0.shape[0]))


fps = 12.0
is_color = True
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")

vid = cv2.VideoWriter(outvid_path, fourcc, 10.0, size, True)

for i in range(0,50):# int(len(imgs_lst))):

    image = input_path +"\\"+ imgs_lst[i]
    img = cv2.imread(image,1)
    img = cv2.resize(img, size) #tried to comment this out... wont work either
    cv2.imshow("img", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

    vid.write(img)

vid.release()
```

if I resize -

```
size = (int(img0.shape[1]/2), int(img0.shape[0]/2))
```

- all works well. 
  My question is whether or not there is a limit on the frame size. I found some other answers regarding the output file size limitation, but nothing about the single frame shape.

(changing fps, format didn't work either)

Comment: It's more about the lmitations set by the particular [VideoIO backend](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html) and the specific coded being used. (Your particular error comes from MS Windows media subsystem, not OpenCV) | What is the exact size of the original? I'd say it's unlikely that you're having issues due to the image being too large. What's more likely is that one of the dimensions (width more likely then height) doesn't satisfy a prerequisite -- odd values can be troublesome, sometimes it has to be multiple of 8 or 16.

Comment: tried opening the file with different players - that didn't help either.
original frame size was (2008, 4802), tried resize to (2000,4800) - didn't help either...